# How to create a contour plot of two functions depending on one variable in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a contour plot in Python where the two axes are two different functions f(c) and g(c) while the contours are different values of c. Preferably in matplotlib but any package will do.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, and change up the c values to pick from as well as the f and g functions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline   

c_values = np.linspace(1,100,100)

f = []
g = []

for c in c_values:
    f_value = c**2 + (1/2)*c
    f.append(f_value)
    g_value = (1/2)*c**3 - c
    g.append(g_value)

f = np.asarray(f)
g = np.asarray(g)

plt.scatter(f, g)
```